# Javascript onMouseClick is not working?

Tags: javascript, android, html, dom, cordova

Here's the code. Basically when I tap on the app nothing happens (yet it is supposed to stop the accelerometer). It's a JS/DOM problem I reckon.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

UNH BSApp

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// The watch id references the current `watchAcceleration`
var watchID = null;

// Wait for PhoneGap to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    startWatch();
}

function onMouseClick() {
a   stopWatch();
}

// Start watching the acceleration
//
function startWatch() {

    // Update acceleration every 0.1 seconds
    var options = { frequency: 10 };

    watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// Stop watching the acceleration
//
function stopWatch() {
    if (watchID) {
        navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
        watchID = null;
    }
}

// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
//
function onSuccess(acceleration) {
    var element = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
    element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '<br />' +
                        'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '<br />' +
                        'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />';
}

// onError: Failed to get the acceleration
//
function onError() {
    alert('onError!');
}

</script>
<style>
    #start {
        display:block;
        border:solid;
    }
</style>


 </head>
  <body>
    <div id="accelerometer">Waiting for accelerometer...</div>
    <div id="start">Start</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you haven't registered for the event click event. You have just created a handler for that. You need to register the event as well.

Comment: Where have you registered the callbacks? Also the event is not onmouseclick. It is onmousedown or, onmouseup, or onclick. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onMouseClick() isn't bound to an event.  Since you're using PhoneGap I'm assuming you'll want to bind to either touchstart or touchend.

```
document.addEventListener("touchend", onMouseClick, false);
```

You'll probably want to add the event listeners once the document is fully loaded as well.

Comment: Touchend is not working :/ I am adding the listener in OnDeviceReady

Comment: Taking a bit of a flyer on this one as I don't have your updated code, but you may have to call preventDefault() first.  Some additional insight here:  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4549

Answer (score 0):

your method OnMouseClick  is never call. You must assign a event listener to something(a div, or the whole document), and if the event is trigger then your OnMouseClick will be call.

Something like :

```
 document.addEventListener("click", onMouseClick, false);
```

Comment: Click is not working either - basically I added a device listener in OnDeviceReady for the click event with a stopWatch() responder